# how i can save date and time by php with sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, date

im working in php and sql erver application i try to save date to sql server by php but it saved wrong date ex:
 if current date 24/4/2011 12:50 am it saved in sql server 11/9/1970  why? what i should do to save current date and time in sql server db by php language

Comment: More information is needed if we are to be of help here. For instance, do you need sql server connection instructions? A sample query? PHP code? All of the above?

Comment: What code did you use to write the date?

Comment: @user despite the bad start, welcome to SO. You will need to ask more detailed questions to get answers here. Please always add the code you are using that doesn't work, and as many details as you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tablename set mydate=current_timestamp
```

my best guess

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving to a `datetime` or `date` field use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`